# asp.net gridview edit button doesn't update

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit

When I enter new data and press update button it saves the old data (data that I want it to update).

```
public void fill()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from school ",con );
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = rd;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    fill();
}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    int id = int.Parse(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text);
    string  stu =((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
    int age = int.Parse(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE school SET  stu_name=@stu_name,age=@age where id=@id ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stu_name", stu));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter ("@age",age));

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    fill();
}
```

he problem that the values that assigned to name,age are the existing values in the database not the new values which I entered in the runtime
any one can help me?? 
thanks in advance

Comment: what do you have in page_load,can you post that code?

Comment: Welocme to SO. what you have written on page load?

Comment: People still use web forms?

Comment: IN page load I call "fill" function only
fill();

Comment: @Nick what people use today instead of web forms?

Comment: If you're doing .NET on the web you would most benefit from ASP.NET MVC 3+ with the Razor view engine.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and watching the life Cycle? Most likely you need an `if(!PostBack)` around your `fill();` in `page_load`.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've had that issue before, so I know where you're coming from... :) Will you mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

You are repopulating the grid every time you edit it.

Call `fill();`  on grid init instead.

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem,
the problem that the values that assigned to name,age are the existing values in the database

Answer (score 0):

Here's some info on the [Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of a web form. I think all you need is to wrap your `fill();` in an `if` statement. Because `page_load` happens before your event handler, you reload from the db on top of the values that were entered.

```
if(!PostBack)
{
  fill();
}
```